# Need help in finding counterexample

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to find example that this isn't correct:

Let $R_1,R_2,R_3$ be binary relations on set $A$. Prove that this is not correct: $(R_1\cup R_2)\circ R_3 \supseteq(R_1\circ R_3)\cup(R_2\circ R_3)$

Comment: There are two conventions to composition of relations. Could you please add your definition for the composition as well?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is the standard convention not the one that coincides with $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))$ where $f(x)=y\iff\langle x,y\rangle\in f$?

Comment: @Mario, since we often write $x\mathrel{R}y$ for $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$, and $\langle x,y\rangle$ is in the composition of $R_1$ and $R_2$ if there is some $z$ such that $\langle x,z\rangle\in R_1$ and $\langle z,y\rangle\in R_2$, so writing $x\mathrel{(R_1\circ R_2)} y$ is more natural. But if you think about functions, that's really the other way around. This is why there are two conventions, which are sometimes denoted slightly differently.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I did't know there are two conventions =D We use first one mentioned in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to one convention for writing the composition of two relations, $\langle a,b\rangle\in(R_1\cup R_2)\circ R_3$ if and only if

$$\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_3\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_1\cup R_2\Big)\;.$$

But this is true if and only if

$$\exists x\in A\left(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_3\land\Big(\langle x,b\rangle\in R_1\lor\langle x,b\rangle\in R_2\Big)\right)\;,$$

which in turn is equivalent to

$$\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_3\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_1\Big)\lor\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_3\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_2\Big)$$

and hence to $\langle a,b\rangle\in(R_1\circ R_3)\cup(R_2\circ R_3)$.

According to the other convention, $\langle a,b\rangle\in(R_1\cup R_2)\circ R_3$ if and only if

$$\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_1\cup R_2\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_3\Big)\;,$$

i.e., if and only if

$$\exists x\in A\left(\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_1\lor\langle a,x\rangle\in R_2\Big)\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_3\right)\;,$$

which in turn is equivalent to

$$\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_1\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_3\Big)\lor\exists x\in A\Big(\langle a,x\rangle\in R_2\land\langle x,b\rangle\in R_3\Big)\;,$$

i.e., to $\langle a,b\rangle\in(R_1\circ R_3)\cup(R_2\circ R_3)$.

By either convention, therefore,

$$(R_1\cup R_2)\circ R_3=(R_1\circ R_3)\cup(R_2\circ R_3)\;,$$

and no such counterexample exists.